# Why does the number not show up correctly when I run the program?

Tags: java

You’re going to automate the famous song “99 Bottles of XXX on the wall”.
You will print the lyrics of ALL 99 verses of the song.  *Use a loop!*  If
you don’t know the lyrics, look them up with google.

The program should:

1. Ask the user for their age
2. If the user is 21 or older, ask them if they prefer beer or soda

a.       If they are under 21  OR they prefer soda, then the lyrics are “99
bottles of soda on the wall”

b.      If they are over 21, then it is “99 Bottles of Beer”

*YOU MUST USE A WHILE LOOP and the counter variable must be part of the
print statement!*

So the first verse would be:

99 bottles of soda on the wall

99 bottles of soda

If one of those bottles should fall off the wall

…..98 bottles of soda on the wall

The last verse:

1 bottle of soda on the wall

1 bottle of soda

If that lone bottle of soda should fall off the wall

No bottles of soda on the wall!

So think, what do you need to add to your loop to print the last verse with
the slightly different lyrics?

// here is my code. When I run it the last lyrics show up like this

```
1 of beer on the wall
 1 bottles of beer
 If one of those bottles should fall off the wall
 ...0 bottles of beer on the wall
 0 of beer on the wall
 0 bottles of beer
 If that lone bottle of beer should fall off the wall
 No bottles of beer on the wall
```

// how can I  make "0" bottle part not to show up??

```
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

           int age, beverage;


           System.out.println("Please type in your age");
           age = user.nextInt();

           user.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Would you like soda or beer? soda=1 beer=2");
           beverage = user.nextInt();

        if(age<21 || beverage==1)
           {
           int bottles = 99;
            while( 1<= bottles){
                System.out.println(bottles+" of soda on the wall");
                System.out.println(bottles+" bottles of soda");
                System.out.println("If one of those bottles should fall off the wall");
                bottles--;
                System.out.println("..."+bottles+" bottles of soda on the wall");
            if(bottles==0){
                System.out.println(bottles+" of soda on the wall");
                System.out.println(bottles+" bottles of soda");
                System.out.println("If that lone bottle of soda should fall off the wall");
                System.out.println("No bottles of soda on the wall");
            }
        }
    }
        if(age>=21 && beverage == 2)
        {
            int bottles=99;
            while(1<= bottles){
                System.out.println(bottles+" of beer on the wall");
                System.out.println(bottles+" bottles of beer");
                System.out.println("If one of those bottles should fall off the wall");
                bottles--;
                System.out.println("..."+bottles+" bottles of beer on the wall");
            if(bottles==0){
                System.out.println(bottles+" of beer on the wall");
                System.out.println(bottles+" bottles of beer");
                System.out.println("If that lone bottle of beer should fall off the wall");
                System.out.println("No bottles of beer on the wall");
            }
        }
    }

        }
    }
```

Comment: @HyunseokSong One of the requirements was to ask the user about soda or beer only if they are 21 or over. Then show Soda if they are under 21 or asked for Soda.

Comment: @SJuan76 Can you explain with more details please?

Comment: I commented about your original question, not about the one that you have edited it into. Please avoid changing one question into another as the people is helping you; if you have more issues, mark the correct answer as accepted and post a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the loop test conditions reversed. Also, I would implement this with `printf` using [`Formatter` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). Then you can include the beverage in the format. It works if I run it like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bottles = 99;

    System.out.println("Please type in your age");
    int age = user.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Would you like soda or beer? soda=1 beer=2");
    int beverage = user.nextInt();
    String drink = (age >= 21 && beverage == 2) ? "beer" : "soda";
    while (bottles > 1) { //  <-- swap 1 and bottles.
        System.out.printf("%d bottles of %s on the wall%n", bottles, drink);
        System.out.printf("%d bottles of %s%n", bottles, drink);
        System.out.println("If one of those bottles "
                + "should fall off the wall");
        bottles--;
        System.out.printf("... %d bottles of %s on the wall.%n", bottles,
                drink);
    }
    System.out.printf("%d bottle of %s on the wall%n", 1, drink);
    System.out.printf("%d bottle of %s%n", 1, drink);
    System.out.printf("If that lone bottle of %s should fall off the wall%n",
                drink);
    System.out.printf("No bottles of %s on the wall!%n", drink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(age>=21 && beverage==2)
       int bottles = 99; /* initialize bottles here*/
```

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference. Why was this accepted? Did it actually do anything?